# Logging requests and responses to console in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, hapi.js

I'm trying to log all requests and responses to the console in a Hapi server using Good. I seem to be able to log responses to some extent but it's not logging the body, and for requests I'm not getting anything at all. Here is my attempt so far

```
const server = new require('hapi').Server();
server.connection({ port: 8081 });

// ... routes ...

server.register({
    register: require('good'),
    options: {
        reporters: {
            console: [{
                module: 'good-squeeze',
                name: 'Squeeze',
                args: [{ error: '*', log: '*', request: '*', response: '*' }]
            }, { module: 'good-console' }, 'stdout']
        }
    }
}, (error) => {
    if(error)
        return console.error(error);
    server.start(() => {
        server.log('info', 'Server running at:' + server.info.uri);
    });
});
```

On a given request, I might get `160625/165227.880, [response] http://ip:8081: get / {} 200 (20ms)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by adding the "includes" block into options:

```
server.register({
    register: require('good'),
        options: {
            includes: {
                request: ['payload'],
                response: ['payload']
            },
            reporters: {
             ...
```

This should help with the body of request/response. 
Link: https://github.com/hapijs/good/blob/master/API.md#options

Comment: Its not working with following versions :"good": "8.1.1",
    "good-console": "7.1.0",
    "good-squeeze": "^5.1.0",
    "hapi": "17.6.0",